# "I realized I had forgotten something" vs "I realized having forgotten something"

Tags: past-perfect

Are the following expressions both correct?

> 1. I realized I had forgotten something.
> 2. I realized having forgotten something.

What is the difference in the meaning (if any)?

Comment: The second expression doesn't seem grammatically correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> 1. I realized [that] I had forgotten something.

This is grammatically correct, and probably what you wanted to say. **realized** is in simple past, so you are talking about something that happened in the past. **had forgotten** is past perfect, which places it before the realizing.

Note that [realize](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/realize) is usually followed by a that-clause, although the **that** is often omitted.

> 2. I realized having forgotten something.

On its own, this sentence is incomplete. **having** is a participle, and **Having forgotten something** is a [participial phrase](http://www.k12reader.com/term/participle-phrase/). Remember that **realize** requires a that-clause, and a phrase won't do. (A clause contains a verb, a phrase does not).

You might use it in a sentence like this, where there is an additional that-clause:

> Having forgotten something, I realized that I would have to go back and get it.

Comment: The verb Realize is usually followed by a that-clause, that is the point. Thx :)

Comment: The point, @Taiki is that your second sentence is ungrammatical.

Answer (score 3):

*To realize* is a reporting verb that can be followed either by ["that- clause"](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/verb-patterns-verb-that-clause) or [a clause starting with a question word (what, how, etc.)](http://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/reporting-verbs/). In "that-clause", *that* is often omitted, like it was in your first sentence.

Examples:

> Only then did I realize that he was telling the truth.
>
> Looking in his eyes, I realized how serious he was.
>
> Having read the letter, I realized what she really meant by saying that.

As for your second sentence, I can't but absolutely agree with JavaLatte.

P.S. The provided links will lead you to the lists of numerous reporting verbs  and their usage to help you further your English.

Answer (score -1):

In the first sentence at the moment you realized what you forgot, it was too late.

> the door was already slammed when I realized I had forgotten my keys.

In the second one, *having* is the progressive form: at the moment you realized it, you could still correct the problem:

> before I slammed the door I realized having forgotten my keys.